# How to fix these Devexpress 9.2.13 to 15.2 conversion errors?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have an problem, I'm upgrading .net project in devExpress 9.2 to 15.2. But my errors are below, could you help me how can I fix these errors.

> 'PrintingSystemBase' does not contain a definition for 'PreviewFormEx'

Comment: are you sure that you are referencing the correct assembly / dll version for the upgrade.. remove all old references and add in the correct reference for the updated and or version of the conversion that you are using..

Comment: Typo corrected and reformatted post

Answer (score 1):

This was a breaking change going from Devexpress 9 to 10.

Take a look at this post on the DevExpress forum :

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q260989

So PreviewFormEx doesn't exist anymore and you have to use ReportPrintTool instead.